# I am able to mass assign a variable in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What I've come to understand is if a variable is not explicitly declared in

`params.require(:emergency).permit(...)`

the variable can not be mass assigned however when I run my test it passes and when I go into Rails console and type in

```
e = Emergency.new(id:10); 
e.save, =>true returns
```

Which is really strange to me , is there a setting in my rails application thats faulty?

```
def create
    @emergency = Emergency.new(emergency_params)
end

def emergency_params
    params.require(:emergency).permit(:fire_severity,:police_severity,:medical_severity,:code)

end


test 'POST /emergencies/ cannot set id' do
    post '/emergencies', emergency: { id: 1, fire_severity: 1, police_severity: 2, medical_severity: 3 }

    assert_equal 201, response.status

end
```

Comment: Probably worth putting a link to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html -- or some other reference showing the expected behavior -- somewhere in the question.

Comment: Question: How is `ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` set?

Comment: Charles Duffy thank you , you solved it.

Comment: Ahh. I'll add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html --

Ensure that `ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` is set to `:raise` if you want an exception raised in this scenario.